# Domain of ellipse constant $y\sqrt{2x^2+4y^2+18}-x=c$

Tags: calculus, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

For the function $$ f(x,y)=y\sqrt{2x^2+4y^2+18}-x$$
Find the domain of $c$ such that the equation $$f(x,y)=c$$ is an ellipse.

I tried it two times in desmos while taking $c$ as slider and I found no value of c gives ellipse shape.
I think the question is wrong. What you have to say about this ?

I tried analytically also by squaring both sides but I'm getting $y^4$ which is not allowing me to convert that equation in generalised ellipse shape. Thanks

Comment: This cannot be an ellipse.

Comment: Yes the product of $y \sqrt{\cdot}$ is producing a shape other than an ellipse, I wonder if it is a typo? without it, one can rearrange and investigate different values of $c$ to sketch ellipses.

Comment: Thanks for confirming :) but this same question is uoaded on Chegg which is solved there and 100% positive rating there. 